# Possible to Disable CodeReloader in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, distillery

The `CodeReloader` (in `dev` mode) is using `Mix.Config`. This fails when using distillery releases in `dev_mode` because `mix` is not available in releases.

Is it possible to completely disable `CodeReloader` in a Phoenix app, such that my app will not fail to start in a `dev_mode` release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your applications `/config/dev.exs` you will have something along the lines of

```
config :my_app_web, MyApp.Web.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]
```

Just change `code_reloader: true` to `code_reloader: false`. Or you could remove the following code from your `MyApp.Endpoint`

```
if code_reloading? do
  socket "/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
  plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
  plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
end
```